# In Subclipse, is there a quicker way to commit changes to SVN?

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

To commit my changes in Eclipse to SVN using Subclipse, I have been right-clicking on my project, selecting Team, and then selecting Commit. Is there a faster way to do this, like a key press or an icon I can click?

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts for eclipse and svn are not created by default. But you can go to:

Window > Preferences > General > Keys

and then assign your preffered shortcuts for the svn operations. [image]